# call value inside a JS variable as a JS function name

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a function to perform actions but name of the function is inside a variable...

below code will get the URL's hashed part example: #JHON and remove # and store it inside URLHASH variable..example: JHON

```
  var urlhash = document.location.hash;
  urlhash = urlhash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
```

always there is a function name from that value inside variable and i want to call value inside that variable as a function name

```
  window.onload=function() {
    Value inside URLHASH variable should run as a name of a variable. example: jhon();
  };
```

Is it possible ? I tried some codes but it calls variable name as a function not value inside the variable..help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access attributes of objects as if they are array indexes, so for example, you could run `getElementById` this way:

```
document["getElementById"]("#myid");
```

so& if you know beforehand of which object the function will be a member, you can access it this way. functions in the global scope are methods of the window object. However, if the hash may contain expressions like `#document.write()`, you would have to do some parsing. it could work like this

```
window.onload=function() {
    var urlhash = document.location.hash, current_element = window;
    urlhash = urlhash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
    elements = urlhash.split(".");
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
        current_element = current_element[elements[i]];
    }
    //execute the actual function
    current_element();
};
```

Comment: Yeah this is perfect for me..works better than expected..thnks alot sys.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
window[urlhash]();
```

This will invoke a function whose name is the *value* of the `urlhash` variable, defined in the context of `window`. Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx6JH/)**.

Comment: Where's your function defined? Can you give me an example? Take at look at this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/k9yxc/

Comment: is your function in the global scope, or part of a different object. Does the hash contain dots (`#myobject.dosomething`)? if so, take a look at my answer, it covers how to parse the hash. If your function is stored in a different object, you can just replace `window` in this answer with the name of your object.

Comment: Sorry Jaoa..my bad..! there was two onload functions on the same page..that's why it didn't work for me..thanks alot..